# macでNginxへのアクセスが403 Forbiddenとなる

Tags: macos, nginx

brew経由でmacにインストールしたNginxへのアクセスで403 Forbiddenと表示されてしまいます。

環境
OS Capitan
Nginx 1.8.1

Nginxへのアクセスは`localhost:8080`にアクセスしています。

nginx.confは下記の通りです。(デフォルトのままです。コメント行は削除しています。)

```
worker_processes  1;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

なぜ403となってしまうのか見当がつきません。
インストール先のフォルダ`html`は下記のようになっており
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 My  admin      16  2 24 16:20 html -> ../../../var/www`
フォルダ`www`下のファルは下記のように配置されています。
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 My  admin  537  1 26 23:39 50x.html`
`-rwxr-xr-x  1 My  admin  612  1 26 23:39 index.html`
`r`権限が付いているので読み取り可能と思うのですが何か考えられる問題ありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/218583/403-forbidden-error-on-mac-osx-apache-and-nginx)に同じような質問があがっておりました。
実際にファイルが置いてあるフォルダの上の階層にもnobodyがアクセスできるようになっていないと
エラーになるようです。（環境作って確認すればよいのですが、出先で確認できず…）

以下、引用になります。

> What are the permissions on /Users/me, /Users/me/Documents and /Users/me/Documents/workspace? All of the folders in the tree need to be readable by the nobody user.

Comment: htmlと同じフォルダ内にhtml_2フォルダを作成し、そこにindex.htmlをコピーして、server { }内にrootディレクティブを追加し、html_2までのパスを明示的に追加した所、うまくいきました。server内でrootを明示的に絶対パスで指定していなかったのが問題だったのかも知れません。(server内のrootは指定しなければインストール元のパスが使われると考えていました。間違い？)
なお、htmlのパスをrootで明示的に設定し、`www`とその上のフォルダ全てに全ユーザ読み取り権限を追加しましたが何故かこちらはうまくいきませんでした。

Answer (score 0):

シンボリックリンクの有効・無効を設定するパラメータがあるようです。
[nginxの公式サイト](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#disable_symlinks)に関連する記事を見つけました。

> Syntax:    disable_symlinks off;
>   disable_symlinks on | if_not_owner [from=part];
>   Default:    
>   disable_symlinks off;
>   Context:    http, server, location
>
> Determines how symbolic links should be treated when opening files:

この対応設定で問題が解決していることから、上記の設定が有効になっていると思います。

> server { }内にrootディレクティブを追加し、html_2までのパスを明示的に追加した所、うまくいきました。